# Presentation of terrain and sub-terrain data in 3D using Qgis

Tags: qgis, representation, qgis2threejs

I have DEM of karst and .shp files of caves in that area exported from "speleoGIS" Therion
http://therion.speleo.sk/

Qgis2threejs is amazing in making visualisation of 3D sourface, which is easy to share and present.
But how can I add there models of caves, when Qgis2threejs allows me to use only polyline file?
And it is possible to add there such format as .dxf?

Comment: Why don't you convert your .dxf files to a GIS format type ie : shapefile A plugin does the work for you : [tadaa](http://docs.qgis.org/1.8/fr/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_dxf2shape_converter.html)

Comment: Thx a lot, but model as shapefile is main point of my question. Anyway, that plugin is not converting that .dxf to .shp. After clicking OK it does nothing. And it offers only lines. And I do have polyline shp of that cave. But I need polygons in my model.

Comment: Specifically for the DXF issue, you don't need a plugin, you can just load a DXF in QGIS and save as a shapefile.

Comment: What do you mean by models of caves? Are you talking about 3D meshes?